# Dask Distributed - how to run one task per worker, making that task running on all cores available into the worker?

Tags: python, dask-distributed, cpu-cores

I'm very new at using `distributed` python library. I have 4 workers and i have successfully launched some parallel runs using 14 cores (among the 16 available) for each worker, resulting in 4*14=56 tasks running in parallel.

But how to proceed if I would like only one task at once in each worker. In that way, I expect one task using the 14 cores in parallel on the worker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dask workers maintain a single thread pool that they use to launch tasks.  Each task always consumes one thread from this pool.  You can not tell a task to take many threads from this pool.

However, there are other ways to control and restrict concurrency within dask workers.  In your case you might consider defining [worker resources](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html).  This would let you stop many big tasks from running at the same time on the same workers.

In the following example we define that each worker has one `Foo` resource and that each task requires one `Foo` to run.  This will stop any two tasks from running concurrently on the same worker.

```
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786 --resources Foo=1
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786 --resources Foo=1
```

.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client('scheduler-address:8786')
futures = client.map(my_expensive_function, ..., resources={'Foo': 1})
```

Comment: This is an incredibly important answer when running pytorch models with num_workers > 0. Concurrency is killer, with hanging dask workers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for when you wish to assign resource constraints when starting  workers in python rather than at the command line:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import delayed
import time
import os

client_with_foo = Client(processes = False,
    n_workers= 2,
    threads_per_worker=10,
    resources = {'foo':1}
               )

@delayed
def do_work(cmd=None, interval=2):
    time.sleep(interval)
    return None


task_graph = []
for i in range(10):
    task_graph.append(do_work())

start = time.time()
result = client_with_foo.compute(task_graph, resources = {'foo':1})
output = client_with_foo.gather(result)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Ten 2-second tasks distributed across two workers takes 10 seconds to execute so the output of the above code is approximately 10.