# Dask Gateway, set worker resources

Tags: dask, dask-kubernetes, dask-gateway

I am trying to set the resources for workers as per the [docs here](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html), but on a set up that uses Dask Gateway.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to follow the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052535/dask-distributed-how-to-run-one-task-per-worker-making-that-task-running-on-a), but using Dask Gateway.

I haven't been able to find a reference to worker resources in the [ClusterConfig options](https://gateway.dask.org/api-server.html), and I tried the following ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602782/is-it-possible-to-assign-worker-resources-to-dask-distributed-worker-after-creat)), which doesn't seem to work:

```py
def set_resources(dask_worker):
    dask_worker.set_resources(task_limit=1)
    return dask_worker.available_resources, dask_worker.total_resources

client.run(set_resources)

# output from a 1 worker cluster
> {'tls://255.0.91.211:39302': ({}, {})}


# checking info known by scheduler
cluster.scheduler_info

> {'type': 'Scheduler',
 'id': 'Scheduler-410438c9-6b3a-494d-974a-52d9e9fss121',
 'address': 'tls://255.0.44.161:8786',
 'services': {'dashboard': 8787, 'gateway': 8788},
 'started': 1632434883.9022279,
 'workers': {'tls://255.0.92.232:39305': {'type': 'Worker',
   'id': 'dask-worker-f95c163cf41647c6a6d85da9efa9919b-wvnf6',
   'host': '255.0.91.211',
   'resources': {}, #### still {} empty dict
   'local_directory': '/home/jovyan/dask-worker-space/worker-ir8tpkz_',
   'name': 'dask-worker-f95c157cf41647c6a6d85da9efa9919b-wvnf6',
   'nthreads': 4,
   'memory_limit': 6952476672,
   'services': {'dashboard': 8787},
   'nanny': 'tls://255.0.92.232:40499'}}}
```

How can this be done, either when the cluster is created using the `config.yaml` of the helm chart (ideally, a field in the cluster options that a user can change!) for Dask Gateway, or after the workers are already up and running?

Comment: Interesting, I can replicate this on a local cluster also...

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to specify this, at least on Kubernetes, is through the [`KubeClusterConfig.worker_extra_container_config`](https://gateway.dask.org/api-server.html#c.KubeClusterConfig.worker_extra_container_config).  This is my yaml snippet for a working configuration (specifically, this is in my config for the daskhub helm deploy):

```yaml
dask-gateway:
  gateway:
    backend:
      worker:
        extraContainerConfig:
          env:
          - name: DASK_DISTRIBUTED__WORKER__RESOURCES__TASKSLOTS
            value: "1"
```

An option to set worker resources isn't exposed in the [cluster options](https://gateway.dask.org/cluster-options.html), and isn't explicitly exposed in the [`KubeClusterConfig`](https://gateway.dask.org/api-server.html#kubernetes).  The specific format for the environment variable is described [here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html#specifying-resources).  Resource environment variables need to be set before the dask worker process is started, I found it doesn't work when I set [`KubeClusterConfig.environment`](https://gateway.dask.org/api-server.html#c.KubeClusterConfig.environment).

Using this, I am able to run multithreaded numpy (`np.dot`) using mkl in a dask worker container that has been given 4 cores.  I see 400% CPU usage and only one task assigned to each worker.